# How does Facebook's Like Button have cross-domain access to add HTML to the parent window?

Tags: javascript, facebook, cross-domain

Disclaimer: I'm going to do my best to explain what I'm after, but I have pretty limited knowledge about cross-domain policies. I have searched around Stack, but if there's an answer I missed, please let me know.

We implemented the standard [Facebook Like/Send button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) on our site. The `Like` and `Send` buttons live inside an iFrame pointing to facebook.com.

When you click on the `Send` button, HTML is appended as a sibling of the Facebook iFrame (ie. to our DOM).

What I want to know is how FB was able to add HTML to their div on our site without violating cross-domain policies.

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tracyfu/L4a9N/). To see what's happening, inspect the DOM while clicking `Send`.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or proof that it does this? I haven't seen that happening - for me it's adding it inside the iframe but absolute positioning it outside the button

Comment: Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tracyfu/L4a9N/). If you click `Send` while inspecting the DOM, an `fb_edge_comment_widget` span is being appended to the `fb-like` div.

Comment: Well, the Facebook JavaScript SDK is living “inside” of your page, so why shouldn’t it be able to manipulate your DOM like _any other_ script living inside your page …? No black magic going on here, really.

Comment: JS from within an iFrame should not be able to access any script in the parent if the domains are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @CBroe for pointing me toward the answer:

via [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage)

`window.postMessage` is a method for safely enabling cross-origin communication. Normally, scripts on different pages are only allowed to access each other if and only if the pages which executed them are at locations with the same protocol (usually both http), port number (80 being the default for http), and host (modulo document.domain being set by both pages to the same value). window.postMessage provides a controlled mechanism to circumvent this restriction in a way which is secure when properly used.

Answer (score 0):

Because you add send button with javascript, not with iframe. Iframe is producing when your page is loading/just after loaded.

Since this reason script is able to reach your and Iframe's content and DOM elements and edits them. As you know and mentioned, iframe cannot reach it's parent anyway.

Comment: Thank you for responding Enes. The question isn't how the parent is able to manipulate the parent... that part I understand. What's happening seems to be that the iFrame is telling the parent to append the `fb_edge_comment_widget` span. See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tracyfu/L4a9N/). Thoughts?

Comment: That’ “normal” cross-domain communication, like FB uses for a lot of stuff when you embed their plugins. Done via _postMessage_ in modern browsers, and via some workarounds in older browsers.

Comment: I tried to say, iframe is working with some behaviour. And,

For example, when iframe have <span id="addToParent"> tag in it, js is in your parent page checks this tag and take it to parent page. That is what i tried to say if I can, I'm happy :)

Comment: If I understand what you're saying, you're suggesting that the parent is watching the child window for changes to the DOM. I believe that is also a violation of cross-domain policies :(

Comment: No, as I know, parent domain can check child with a little bit JS code.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your responses. It seems like postMessage is the answer. It took some digging to figure out what your comment meant. As I prefaced my question with my limited understanding of cross-domain policies, it would've been helpful to get a more descriptive explanation of what you meant by "normal" cross-domain communication and guidance to what ["postMessage"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) actually refers to.